# Write python script to remove specified text form PDF files

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, pypdf, pdf-extraction

I am struggling to remove text from a pdf file. I know this can be performed manually with PDF editors but I have a few PDF files to modify. The code I have so far is able to recognise all the text in a pdf file but dpes not remove th text when it is re-written as the output file.

here is the script I tried
EDIT: I do not want to redact a pdf I want to remove the text from the PDF

```
import PyPDF2

# Open the PDF file in read-binary mode
with open('C:/inputput.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    # Create a PdfFileReader object to read the PDF file
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

    # Get the first page of the PDF file
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)

    # Get the page's content as a string
    page_content = page.extractText()

    # Replace the text to be removed with an empty string
    modified_content = page_content.replace('words to replace', '')

    # If the entire text box was removed, remove the text box itself
    if not modified_content.strip():
        page.getContents().getObject().update({PyPDF2.utils.b_("Filter"): PyPDF2.utils.b_("FlateDecode"), PyPDF2.utils.b_("Length"): 0})
    
    # Replace the page's content with the modified content

    # Create a PdfFileWriter object to write the modified PDF to a new file
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(page)

    # Save the modified PDF to a new file
    with open('output_file22.pdf', 'wb') as output_file:
        pdf_writer.write(output_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

Removing text from a PDF is called **redaction**. This should help you along when you're googling the problem.

If you're open to using another library, you can do this using `borb` with the following code:

```py
#!chapter_005/src/snippet_006.py
import typing
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import RegularExpressionTextExtraction
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.annotation.redact_annotation import RedactAnnotation

def main():

    # read the Document
    # extract all occurences of a regular expression
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    l: RegularExpressionTextExtraction = RegularExpressionTextExtraction("[lL]orem .* [dD]olor")
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])

    # add a redaction annotation for each matching group
    # this code only does so on page 0, but you can of course modify that
    for i, m in enumerate(l.get_matches()[0]):
        for r in m.get_bounding_boxes():
            page.add_annotation(RedactAnnotation(r))

    # apply redaction annotations
    # Redaction is a two-step process according to the PDF specification.
    # This allows multiple users to collaborate on redacting a document;
    # you can still see where others users want to remove text all
    # the way up until you apply the redaction annotations.
    doc.get_page(0).apply_redact_annotations()

    # store the modified PDF
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as out_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, doc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To learn more about redaction and `borb`, check out the examples repository [here](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#66-adding-redaction-annotations).

Comment: thank for you feedback, The code you supplied does not work , it gives the following error:

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\geometry\rectangle.py", line 25, in __init__
    assert width >= 0, "A Rectangle must have a non-negative width."

AssertionError: A Rectangle must have a non-negative width.

I do not want to redact text from a PDF i want to remove it completely

Comment: Adding redaction annotations, applying those annotations, and then saving the modified file will remove the text.

Comment: Can you share the PDF you're using?